# HAProxy - request path rewriting always to /

Tags: redirect, amazon-s3, haproxy

I have configuration for HAProxy which translate from 
https://sub-domain.domain.com/file.html to 
https://s3.server.com/sub-domain.domain.com/file.html

It works, but I need to change it to translate form

https://sub-domain.domain.com/file.html to 
https://s3.server.com/sub-domain.domain.com/

It should ignore path, and always redirect to /

I tried to change:
http-request set-path /%[req.hdr(host),lower]%[path]
to
http-request set-path /%[req.hdr(host),lower]

But it makes my browser redirect from
https://sub-domain.domain.com/
to
https://sub-domain.domain.com/sub-domain.domain.com/

This is my full configuration:

```
global
    daemon
    maxconn 200000

defaults
    mode http
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 50000ms
    timeout server 50000ms

frontend http-in
    bind *:80
    bind *:443
    default_backend servers

backend servers
    http-request set-path /%[req.hdr(host),lower]%[path]
    http-request set-header Host myserver.s3.com
    server server1 myserver.amazonaws.com maxconn 200000
```

Thank you in advance for any help.